# Replacing string up to matching pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string such as this one `QH AAPL|5M|20190101093000|20190208170000|12347:M01/02/2019|F04:00:00|H154.4|L153.01|O154.4|T154|V3257` and I'd like to replace all characters at the beginning of the string up to `:M` with `M`.

So the remaining string should be `M01/02/2019|F04:00:00|H154.4|L153.01|O154.4|T154|V3257`.

I have no idea how to get this done in Python regex. Please help!

Comment: Will :M be the first place where the colon(:) is encountered in all strings?

Comment: So you don't want to replace anything you just want to extract a substring: where is your code?Did you try to do anything at all?

Comment: You do not need regex to do that. Just find the index of `:M` and then slice the list to that index to get the remaining string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python `str.find()` method does the trick. Here an example:

```
a = "QH AAPL|5M|20190101093000|20190208170000|12347:M01/02/2019|F04:00:00|H154.4|L153.01|O154.4|T154|V3257"

print(a[a.find(":M") + 1:])  # -> M01/02/2019|F04:00:00|H154.4|L153.01|O154.4|T154|V3257
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to do it with regex, have a look at the following example:

```
import re

a = "QH AAPL|5M|20190101093000|20190208170000|12347:M01/02/2019|F04:00:00|H154.4|L153.01|O154.4|T154|V3257"

print(a[re.search(":M", a).start() + 1:])  # -> M01/02/2019|F04:00:00|H154.4|L153.01|O154.4|T154|V3257
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the regex:

```
import re
text = 'QH AAPL|5M|20190101093000|20190208170000|12347:M01/02/2019|F04:00:00|H154.4|L153.01|O154.4|T154|V3257'

regex = re.compile(r'.+:(M.+$)')
match = regex.search(text)

if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```